# Why am I receiving a PartialCredentialsError here

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku

I've been trying to deploy my django app using heroku. I'm handling
uploaded files using aws s3. When I run the site I keep getting the following error. I have added the aws_access_key_id etc. in environment variables.
I don't understand why I am still getting this error message.

PartialCredentialsError at /
Partial credentials found in explicit, missing: aws_access_key_id

I have read that env variables take precedence over the AWS cli config. I don’t really understand the connection though

If anyone has ideas, I would be very grateful :)
I’m a total newb and appreciate any advice. Also will gladly add any information needed to solve this issue

Update: This is an excerpt of the settings.py file in my Project

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "blog-home"

LOGIN_URL = "blog-login"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"

EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("USER")

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("USER_PASS")

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "us-west-2"

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Just a lame error when setting my environment variables on heroku. I had set

ACCESS_KEY_ID="..."

it should have been

AWS_ACCESs_KEY_ID="..."

Answer (score 1):

> I have added the aws_access_key_id etc

Its not fully clear from your question, but it seems that you used `aws_access_key_id` as the actual name of environment variable. If so, then the names should be **capitalized** as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-set):

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

Comment: Yes the AWS Accra and secret key etc are stored in env variables. I have them in all caps. So weird it’s not working. Locally it works but on the Heroku server I’m running into this error

Comment: @Minibumphead I would suggest updating the question with actual information, setup and code examples. WIthout that its only speculation.